# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException UNKNOWN COLUMN

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, java.util.scanner

I am currently trying to scan and parse the file that is not in sql format. I am trying to input all the data into the SQL table but for some reason every time i run the program, i get the error saying unknown column 'what' in 'field list.' So the neither of the data goes through. 'what' is one of the names that is on the text. The table currently has 11 columns. I know I am parsing or scanning it wrong but I cannot figure out where. Here is my code:

```
public class parseTable {

public parseTable (String name) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File(name);
    parse(file);
}

private void parse(File file) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String connectionUser = "";
    String connectionPassword = "";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

    String[] rowInfo = new String[11];
    int count = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){

        //String data = scan.nextLine();

        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());

        while(lineScan.hasNext()){
            String words = lineScan.next();
            if(count < 11){
                rowInfo[count] = words;
                count++;
            }


            else if(count == 11 && words.equals("States")){
                rowInfo[count - 1] = rowInfo[count - 1] + " " + words;
            }

            else{
                String query = "";
                for(int i = 0; i < rowInfo.length; i++)
                {
                    if(query.equals(""))
                    {
                        query = rowInfo[i];
                    }
                    else if(i == 9){
                        query = query + "," + rowInfo[i];
                    }

                    else if(rowInfo[i].equals(null)){
                        query = query + ", " + "NULL";
                    }

                    else
                        query = query + ", " +  "'" + rowInfo[i] + "'";

                }

                stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO dup VALUES(" + query + ")");

                count = 0;
                rowInfo = new String[11];
            }
        }



    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try { if (rs != null) rs.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        try { if (stmt != null) stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        try { if (conn != null) conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

}

And this is the data I'm trying to input:
1   hello   cheese  1111    what@yahoo.com  user    adm street  zip what    USA
2   Alex   cheese   1111    what@yahoo.com  user    adm street  zip what    USA

So this is my new code now, using PrepareStatement. However I still get an error and I looked online for the solution on where I'm making a mistake, but I cant seem to figure out where.

```
   String query = "INSERT INTO mil_table (UserName, NameFirst, NameLast, supportID, EmailAddress, Password,
               IDQ, AddressCity, AddressState, AddressZip, AddressCountry) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

    String[] rowInfo = new String[11];
    int count = 0;
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){

        //String data = scan.nextLine();

        Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());

        while(lineScan.hasNext()){
            String words = lineScan.next();
            if(count < 11){
                rowInfo[count] = words;
                count++;
            }


            else if(count == 11 && words.equals("States")){
                rowInfo[count - 1] = rowInfo[count - 1] + " " + words;
            }

            else{

                for(int i = 0; i <rowInfo.length; i++)
                {
                    pstmt.setString(i + 1, rowInfo[i]);
```

}

```
                //stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO mil_table VALUES(" + query + ")");
                //System.out.println("@" + query + "@");
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
                count = 0;
                rowInfo = new String[11];
            }
        }
```

Comment: It would be better if you use `PreparedStatement` and set each argument one by one rather than concatenating the values and try to pass all of them without proper escape e.g. `what != 'what'`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I tried to using the preparedstatement but i still get some error. I looked online for the preparestatement info, but it didn't really help me.

Comment: What's your new exception? Provide details about it

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Unknown column 'IDQ' in 'field list'. This was the exception i got.

Comment: Well, the exception message is very descriptive. Make sure you have a column called IDQ in your table and that you're using the right spelling on it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yea I did have a wrong spelling in my code for some reason :/ So there are no errors anymore but the second one is not being read and put into the table.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MySQL, you will need to enclose the text inputs with quotes. Try enclosing the String values that you are inserting in quotes and then execute your code.

Comment: That is not required, it is only necessary in some corner cases like using keywords as column names.